# Display Playa inside Matrix

Tags: matrix, playa

Have been looking through the previous solutions in here but still not able to make this work. I am able to display the normal data ok however not the Playa data, it is blank. Any help would be great if possible.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="statistics" dynamic="off" limit="1" url_title="{segment_3}"}
    {title} {!-- Page title --}

    {exp:channel:entries channel="statistics"}

        {stats_driver_points_table} 

            {stats_driver} {!-- Matrix field name with playa inside --}
                {title}  {!-- Playa title, display blank --}
            {/stats_driver}
            {stats_r1_q}  {!-- Displays ok --}
            {stats_r1_q}  {!-- Displays ok --}
            {stats_season_total}  {!-- Displays ok --}

        {/stats_driver_points_table}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have this working now.. turned out that removing it from the embed did the trick

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="statistics" dynamic="no" limit="1" url_title="{segment_3}"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:channel:entries 
        channel="statistics"
        dynamic="no"
    }

{stats_driver_points_table}

    {stats_position}
    
    {stats_driver}
    {driver_fullname}
    {/stats_driver}
    
    {stats_r1_q}
    {stats_r1_c}
    {stats_r2_q}
    {stats_r2_c}
    {stats_season_total}

{/stats_driver_points_table}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

One last thing is that now only "open" entries will display in the playa field, how can I display closed too, if it's possible?

Comment: {stats_driver status="open|closed"}
 {driver_fullname}
 {/stats_driver}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your inner channel entries tag is an embed? I made a couple of changes to your example that may help. Also, try adding prefixes to the matrix field and the playa cell:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="statistics" 
    dynamic="no" 
    limit="1" 
    url_title="{segment_3}"
}
    {title}

    {!-- EMBED --}
    {exp:channel:entries 
        channel="statistics"
        dynamic="no"
    }

        {stats_driver_points_table var_prefix="mx"} {!-- Matrix field --}

            {mx:stats_driver var_prefix="pl"} {!-- Playa column --}
                {pl:title}
            {/mx:stats_driver}

            {mx:stats_r1_q}
            {mx:stats_r1_q}
            {mx:stats_season_total}
        {/stats_driver_points_table}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
    {!-- END EMBED --}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Yes it's an embed. Have tried the above change but no success. I also attempted just to drop in some text before {pl:title} and this doesn't show either, would this be a clue or is that just not going to happen? <pre> {mx:stats_driver var_prefix="pl"} {!-- Playa column --}
               Driver name:{pl:driver_fullname}
            {/mx:stats_driver} </pre>

Comment: If there are no results on the playa field then it would make sense that other text wouldn't display. It could be a status issue on the related entries (the ones with driver_fullname field), what are those set at?

Comment: thanks for reply. i did have it with some open and some closed, so changed to all open but still no display. The playa fields are displaying in the admin within the entry etc.. just not pulling out into the front end.. making me a little crazy ;-)

Comment: Are you sure stats_driver is the correct matrix cell name where your playa related field is? I'd start looking at all the little things, because it seems like it should be working.

Comment: yes seems to be, see screen shot here [link](http://www.whiteflame.eu/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/matrix-playa.jpg)

Comment: ok so I've tried the following and I get a sort of result

{mx:stats_driver_points_table} {!-- Added this line --}
{mx:stats_driver var_prefix="pl"} {!-- Playa column --}
Driver name:{pl:title}
{/mx:stats_driver}

This gives me the details I'm after but I also get extra so it displays as

[301] Driver Name - drievr-name

Obviously not quite right but gets some form of result. Does this help with working it out?

Comment: doing the above gives me the same result whatever data I try to display related to driver

Comment: Can you try testing on just a pared down template with only the relevant code (not an embed) and see if it helps troubleshoot?